# How to host a WCF Service in a reference DLL via an MVC Website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3

I hope that title is clear enough.

I have 2 projects, MyProject.Website (ASP.NET MVC3 Front End) and MyProject.WcfService. When i host the website, i'd rather not have to host two websites inside of IIS, i'd like to be able to host just MyProject.Website and inside of that reference MyProject.WcfService.

I know i can do this via ServiceHost, which should work, but is there a better way?

Comment: Why not just use it as an assembly reference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check this post where i demostrated how you can host wcf service dll

[Create, Host(Self Hosting, IIS hosting) and Consume WCF servcie](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/11/create-hostself-hosting-iis-hosting-and.html)

**IIS hosting**

1. To host same WCF library in your application create WCF Web application project using WCF web application.
2. Delete the files created in the IService.cs and Service.cs file from App_Code folder
3. Include WCF library *.dll file which we created.
4. Open Service.svc file and modify the single line in it

   -- <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfServiceLibrary.Service1" %>
5. Change the web service WEB.Config file to to expose service to client. i.e you need to create Same element as listed above in in the app.config file of service library.